# How to prevent Jenkins from resuming an aborted job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I had aborted a job by clicking the [x] button next to it's name in the *Build Executor Status* panel of Jenkins, yet the job is still present and waiting.

[image]

Even when I restart Jenkins it will resume building.  When I take a look at the console I see:

> Sending interrupt signal to process Click here to forcibly terminate
>   running steps java.io.IOException: Aborting build     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
>     at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)    at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585) [**SNIP**]
>
> Finished: ABORTED Resuming build at Tue Oct 25 14:56:36 CDT 2016 after
>   Jenkins restart

I believe this version of my Pipeline script also included an "Input" block, it's possible the job was aborted as it was waiting for Input if that makes a difference

Answer (score 3):

I clean these up by going Manage Jenkins -> Script Console and then putting in code like this:

`Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(
    "tpr-ereg")
    .getBuildByNumber(24).
    finish(hudson.model.Result.ABORTED, 
       new java.io.IOException("Aborting build"));`

NOTE: the above may need to be all on one line in the Script Console

Comment: I think you meant `24` instead of `4`. Alas, no effect! This thing is just stuck!

Comment: Bonus points if you can provide a groovy way to detect these jobs! They do not show up on Executor lists.